# I can't access the images in the file codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

When I go to the incoming link, it redirects to the home page and the url does not go.

File structure

```
-codeigniter-case
 --application
 --system
 --img
  ---jonatan.jpg
```

`view`

```
<img src="<?=base_url()?>codeigniter-case/img/jonatan.jpg">

// i get this output : http://localhost:8080/codeigniter-case/uploads/img/jonatan.png
```

`.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

`config.php`

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Comment: Might be caused by the extra space in the conditions `! -f` and `! -d` in the `.htaccess`, try removing those: `!-f` and `!-d`.

Answer (score 0):

You must enter your project folder name in base url

```
<img src="<?=base_url()?>uploads/img/jonatan.png">
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost:8080/projectFolderName/';
```

Comment: I did what you said but it doesn't work.

Comment: <img src="<?=base_url()?>img/jonatan.png">